# Should one use "the" for three-dimensional space?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> These molecules can rotate in **the** three-dimensional space.

My feeling is that the article should be omitted. I'm not completely sure, though. What grammatical rule should we appeal to?

Comment: It's possible to use *the*, *a*, or nothing at all. It depends on what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Normally the word **the** should be omitted.

There is no general rule. By custom, we treat Euclidean **three-dimensional space** as if it were an uncapitalized proper noun that doesn't take a definite article, like the names of most cities: London, New York, Edinburgh, etc.

> These molecules can rotate in London.
>
> These molecules can rotate in three-dimensional space.

Other mathematical concepts work like **the sky**, e.g. [the Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group), [the Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph), [the A<sub>6</sub> group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group). There is only one of each of these, and the customary **the** makes us regard it as "always in view", always available to be pointed out by **the** (even at first mention). But A<sub>6</sub> by itself, not as a qualifier before "group", works like the names of cities: it doesn't take an article.

However, you would need **the** before **three-dimensional space** in order to narrow down or distinguish the concept from the usual infinite Euclidean space. For example, if you had just defined several vector spaces of varying dimensions, containing polynomials, exactly one of which was three-dimensional, then you could refer to it by "the three-dimensional space". But then you would be talking about math, not molecules.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in omitting 'the' in this case. The case that keeping 'the' in the sentence would be appropriate is when describing a subset of three-dimensional space, like such:

> "These molecules can rotate in the three-dimensional space inside a container."